# adapter for listView sectioned data

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio, baseadapter

how can we create a Adapter (for ListView) which can take categorized data
and show them in a listView with headers and rows,

by categorized data i meant grouped data e.g.

```
record = ["US",("California","Alabama","Alaska","Wisconsin")]
```

the above is a record which holds a country and its states.

i have list of states with their countries and i wanna show it on a listView (sorted by countries) and i want to use country's name as section header of my list 
this is what its going to look like :

**Country1**

state1ofC1

state2ofC1

state3ofC1

**Country2**

state1ofC2

state2ofC2

state3ofC3

................

a basic Adapter  for listView looks like this :

```
public class NewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

which takes one array of records. but how can i create an Adapter which is compatible with Categorized data so that i can use listView with section headers please guide me

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an [ExpandableListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).